# Error While Trying To Enable "Document Sets" Feature Through PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I'm building a script for our SharePoint 2013 sites but before I have it loop I wanted to test the following line to make sure it worked by running it one time only, every time I run it though it throws the following error (even if run it using different site URL's)

*here's the error:*

> Enable-SPFeature : This page has encountered a critical error. Contact
>   your system administrator if this problem persists.
>
> - ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...etEnableFeature:SPCmdletEnableFeature)
>       [Enable-SPFeature    ], WebPartPageUserException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletEnableFeature

*here's what I'm sending:*

```
Enable-SPFeature -Identity 3bae86a2-776d-499d-9db8-fa4cdc7884f8 -Url "MyUrl.com"
```

Has anyone seen this error before when trying to enable features? If so how were you able to resolve it?

Thank you.

Comment: Could be related to your issue: http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/01/fix-for-this-page-has-encountered-critical-error.html. Have you looked at IIS or Sharepoint logs to see what was happenening?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out enabling that feature on the App Server doesn't work. I gave it a try on the Web Server and it work perfectly fine.